# Extjs 4.0.7 grid grouping

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an extended grid. I need to use grouping, doesn't matter if it's remote or not. Grid behaves like grouping, but doesn't show the collapsible field. Shows anything like no groupin, but can't sorting by other columns.

I have `sorters`, `groupField`, `features`, and

```
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
    groupHeaderTpl: '{columnName}: {name}',
    hideGroupedHeader: true,
    remoteRoot: 'projektname',
    startCollapsed: true
});
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Looks fine to me https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gah

Comment: It is a missing setting, Ive run into similar thing and took me a few days to find the missing setting. I could have sworn it was Sencha's bug but it wasn't

Do you have            

 features: [groupingFeature],

or 

eatures: [
                        {
                            ftype: 'grouping',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
                            hideGroupedHeader: true,
                            enableGroupingMenu: false
                        }
                    ],

Answer (score 0):

It is a missing setting, Ive run into similar thing and took me a few days to find the missing setting. I could have sworn it was Sencha's bug but it wasn't

Do you have

```html
features: [groupingFeature],
```

or

```html
features: [
                        {
                            ftype: 'grouping',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
                            hideGroupedHeader: true,
                            enableGroupingMenu: true
                        }
                    ],
```

Comment: I have this `features: [groupingFeature]`